# Docker for Windows - Volumes not working correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am starting to work with Docker for Windows, but I can't make volumes to work with `docker-compose`.

First, I've created a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install nodemon -g
```

Then, a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nodeServer:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - './:/usr/src/app'
    command: bash -c "npm run start"
```

When a volume is declared in the `docker-compose.yml´, it doesn't work.

But, when I try to bind a volume through the command line like this:

```bsh
docker build .

docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app d0d9397e9194 bash
```

It works. I can't understand the difference between these two approaches.

I've checked more than once my configurations:
[image: docker config]

Comment: In your `docker run` command, what's `{PWD}`?

Also, what's the purpose of mapping root (`./`) to the container, if you already have copied it across (see your `Dockerfile`)?

Comment: {PWD} is my current directory. The purpose of mapping `./` is to be able to reproduce any edits inside the container (watch process).

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Could you try removing the single quotes (') in the `volume` mapping? (docker-compose.yaml).

Comment: I've tried it already, but no success. :/